# Как узнать локальный IP адрес типа 10.x.x.x в Colab?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Для tf.data.experimental.service.distribute нужно знать локальный IP адрес DispatchServer, который запущен локально в блокноте Colab. То есть нужен IP, как его видит TPUStrategy.
У меня пока только получилось увидеть 172.28.0.2 через `local_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`, но нужно 10.x.x.x

Comment: а чем вам подсеть 172.x.x.x не угодила? она не менее локальна, чем 10.x.x.x

Comment: А как тогда TPU с адресом 10.x.x.x увидит сервер на 172.х.х.х? Там скорее всего не позволит роутер так сделать или правила. В cloud.google.com там обычно colab и TPU node имеют локальные IP 10.х.х.х, в бесплатном colab наверно тоже также должно быть, только не понятно как узнать.